# How can I make my calculator code repeat without asking the user to input anything? - continuous calculation in Python

Tags: python

```
def calculation():

    num1 = float(input())
    num2 = float(input())
    op = input()

    if op == "+":    #code for addition
        print(num1 + num2)

    elif op == "-": #code for subtraction
        print(num1 - num2)

    elif op == "/": #code for division
        print(num1 / num2)

    elif op == "*": #code for multiplication
        print(num1 * num2)

    #elif ZeroDivisionError:
        #print("Divided by zero")

    else: #code if invalid operator is entered
        print("Invalid operator entered")


calculation() #calling the fucntion
```

Right now the code only runs when I call the function. Id like it to run non-stop, like a physical calculator. I am also trying to sort out how to not break the code if division by 0 occurs. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Ever heard of loops?

Comment: Read about `while` loops using your favorite Python tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

A simple infinite loop will do:

```
while True:
    calculation()
```

You can also shorten your `calculation` function, mapping your symbols to the appropriate [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) functions and handling exceptions as they occur:

```
from operator import add, sub, mul, truediv

ops = {"+": add, "-": sub, "*": mul, "/": truediv}

def calculation():
    num1 = float(input())
    num2 = float(input())
    op = input()

    try:
        print(ops[op](num1, num2))
    except KeyError:
        print("Invalid operator entered")
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("Divided by zero")
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the default way is to use `while True`:

```py
while True:
    # your code here
```

True is by default True, so your program will run until it is manually terminated.

As with the division by zero, you can do

```py
...
elif op == "/": #code for division
    if num2 == 0:
        print('Cannot divide by zero!')
    else:
        print(num1 / num2)
```

Comment: Glad I could help, please mark the answer as accepted if it matches what you were looking for